# WordPress Contact form 7 Редактировать текст заголовка

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

WordPress Contact form 7 Не могу найти, где отредактировать текст заголовка который приходит, сейчас постоянно приходит заголовок c текстом "WordPres". Редактирования заголовка Subjeck: не помогло.
[image: Gmail]

Answer (score 0):

> сейчас постоянно приходит заголовок c текстом "WordPres"

Это не заголовок, а имя отправителя. По умолчанию это название сайта.

Для его изменения нужно настроить "От кого".

[image]

Это в случае, если ВП отправляет сам, с сервера. Если же через SMTP, то там свои настройки.